# Detecting Memory Leak in a web application

Tags: tomcat, memory, memory-leaks

We have a web application written in gwt and deployed in tomcat. The tomcat crashes on outofmemoryexception, so i am trying to look for memory leaks using Jprofiler, jmap/jhat utility and so on.

Here are the issues i see and appreciate the expert's help in tracking down the issue.

I have configured tomcat to run with -Xmx1600m -Xms1024m and enabled gc logging. When i see the gc log after running the application for few hours, i see the following,

```
9850.373: [GC [PSYoungGen: 301459K->10630K(341504K)] 943137K->663019K(1269952K), 0.1711120 secs] [Times: user=0.32 sys=0.02, real=0.17 secs]
9864.412: [GC [PSYoungGen: 320588K->14287K(341376K)] 972976K->668772K(1269824K), 0.1604710 secs] [Times: user=0.24 sys=0.00, real=0.16 secs]
9874.808: [GC [PSYoungGen: 324431K->7800K(377792K)] 978916K->666111K(1306240K), 0.1253720 secs] [Times: user=0.21 sys=0.04, real=0.12 secs]
9884.888: [GC [PSYoungGen: 355320K->7639K(377920K)] 1013631K->670793K(1306368K), 0.1563460 secs] [Times: user=0.23 sys=0.01, real=0.15 secs]
9897.209: [GC [PSYoungGen: 355159K->9687K(423552K)] 1018313K->676330K(1352000K), 0.1368880 secs] [Times: user=0.22 sys=0.05, real=0.14 secs]
9913.372: [GC [PSYoungGen: 403927K->5599K(424000K)] 1070570K->675351K(1352448K), 0.1599430 secs] [Times: user=0.21 sys=0.02, real=0.16 secs]
9999.866: [GC [PSYoungGen: 399839K->6655K(468480K)] 1069591K->678050K(1396928K), 0.2453910 secs] [Times: user=0.37 sys=0.03, real=0.24 secs]
10104.177: [GC [PSYoungGen: 449919K->10830K(472576K)] 1121314K->688787K(1401024K), 0.1271810 secs] [Times: user=0.20 sys=0.03, real=0.12 secs]
10114.859: [GC [PSYoungGen: 454094K->7316K(514240K)] 1132051K->694401K(1442688K), 0.1046640 secs] [Times: user=0.15 sys=0.05, real=0.10 secs]
10127.079: [GC [PSYoungGen: 496084K->6783K(516160K)] 1183169K->699705K(1444608K), 0.1004840 secs] [Times: user=0.17 sys=0.03, real=0.10 secs]
10136.380: [GC [PSYoungGen: 495551K->8800K(516096K)] 1188473K->707881K(1444544K), 0.1615950 secs] [Times: user=0.28 sys=0.04, real=0.16 secs]
10151.757: [GC [PSYoungGen: 500704K->13808K(517696K)] 1199785K->716602K(1446144K), 0.2068230 secs] [Times: user=0.32 sys=0.09, real=0.20 secs]
10184.481: [GC [PSYoungGen: 505712K->4543K(519488K)] 1208506K->716201K(1447936K), 0.2158960 secs] [Times: user=0.32 sys=0.05, real=0.22 secs]
10206.485: [GC [PSYoungGen: 499647K->12190K(520192K)] 1211305K->728137K(1448640K), 0.2251280 secs]
```

My understanding from the gc.log is the following,

Young generation is using 12190K after Garbage collection.
Old Generation is using 728137K after Garbage collection.

So in total the application is using 740M. Am i right in my understanding?

If not, what is right interpretation of this log file?

If yes, i have also looked at the system resource usage using htop  ( am running it on linux ) which is showing the tomcat process is using 1419M.

Why is the difference in the memory usage?

Appreciate you help!
Thanks.

Comment: try adding the startup flag -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError for further diagnosis. next time the JVM runs out of memory, it will dump the contents of the heap. That should give you further information. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memleaks-137499.html#gdyrr

Comment: also based on the young gen sizes i don't see an OOMException in that log provided. for example your last entry: 499647K->12190K Young gen recovered around 95%. The old gen was reduced from 1211305K->728137K which is a reduction of around 45%. There appears to be lots of space to your cap @ 1600m

Comment: I have already added the  -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError but OOM hasn't occured yet.

Comment: for profiling purposes, hprof + MAT may show you leak suspects. You would have to load test your application to get valuable results

Comment: I am using jprofiler and jconsole and can see that gc is recovering most of the used space. When the application is accessed by a lot of users the memory usage grows and gc collects very well but our web server is killed by the operating system saying the following error Jul 18 04:55:31 seqwd5 kernel: Out of memory: Killed process 16333, UID 501, (java).
Jul 18 04:55:31 seqwd5 kernel: java invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x201d2, order=0, oomkilladj=0
 message

Comment: So you are running out of memory on your Linux box and not from your application?? I notice you have variable -Xms and -Xmx values. some point between those 2 values your system appears to be running out of memory and killing the process requesting memory. If your -Xms and -Xmx are the same value the JVM never has to request memory from the OS.

Comment: I have modified the memory settings -Xms and -Xmx to the same value. What i dont understand is , the jconsole is showing the tomcat usage is 420M and at the same time the server top command shows 1350M as RES. Shouldn't this number be same as the jconsole memory usage number.

Comment: The JVM takes all of the memory it requested during startup and allocates it for its purposes (heap etc). The memory in the heap at any given time is borrowed from that chunk of data which was set aside during startup.

Comment: MAT helped tracking down the class which was holding a lot of objects and never releasing it. It was a class inside GWT. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a memory leak in the GWT Requestfactory which is fixed in 2.4. I just upgraded to that and everything works great.